# Bind to original activerecord method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, bind

I'm implementing a simple soft deletion functionality for multiple of my models. I'm using rails concerns, so i keep the logic in one place (if concerns is the best method is not the question here)

So basicly the call order of the destroy method is:

Model without softdeletion:
1. ActiveRecord::Base.destroy

Model with soft deletion:
1. SoftDeletion.destroy
2. ActiveRecord::Base.destroy

AND NOW TO MY PROBLEM!
In some models, i need to override the destroy method in order to be able to make a hard deletion, when the models has a particular state (basicly letting some logic determine if the should just be soft deletion or totally removed). It works like this:

```
def destroy
     if someValue
         # call original destroy
     else
         # call soft deletion
     end
end
```

With the method call order in mind, how do i get to the original ActiveRecord::Base.destroy ??
calling super inside the overridden destroy only calls the softdeletion destroy.

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem by checking if an additional method is declared on the model "soft_delete_when", and just check if that methods returns true or not.

```
module SoftDeletion
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        scope :active, where("deleted_at is null")
        scope :deleted, where("deleted_at is not null")
    end

    def destroy
        if self.class.instance_methods(false).include? :soft_delete_when
            unless self.soft_delete_when
                super
            else
                touch(:deleted_at)
            end
        else
            touch(:deleted_at)
        end
    end

    def is_destroyed?
        deleted_at != nil
    end

    def undestroy
        update_attribute(:deleted_at, nil)
    end

end
```

I would still very much like to know if there is any way to call super further up the method stack.. Anyone?

Comment: How do you define your soft `destroy`?

Comment: could you plz explain about `SoftDeletion`

Comment: SoftDeletion is a concept where you keep the data but flag the model as deleted. In my implementation a use a timestamp to tell if a model is flagged as deleted.

Comment: could you alias the destroy method in your concern say to destroy_super and call that in place of super ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `alias_method_chain`?

```
module SoftDeletion
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      alias_method_chain :destroy, :soft_delete
    end
  end
  # (...)

  def destroy_with_soft_delete
    if self.class.instance_methods(false).include? :soft_delete_when
      unless self.soft_delete_when
        destroy_without_soft_delete
      else
        touch(:deleted_at)
      end
    else
      touch(:deleted_at)
    end
  end
  # (...)
end
```

and in your `ActiveRecord` class:

```
def destroy
  if someValue
    destroy_without_soft_delete
  else
    destroy_with_soft_delete
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach works just fine. I ended up using both destroy_without_soft_delete and destroy_with_soft_delete in my ActiveRecord model instead of super, to be more explicit about whats going on.